# Making file path part variable using Python

Tags: python, arcpy, date

I am creating a python script to help automate updates.

I am just wondering does anyone know how to make part of my file path a variable, as each month the python script will run via a different file path (only the date will change)

For example
Current workspace is

```
env.workspace = r"X:\Support\Data\Shapes\Dec20\SA"
```

Next month it will be

```
env.workspace = r"X:\Support\Data\Shapes\Jan21\SA"
```

Is there a way i can make the "Date" a variable?

I.e

```
DATE_IS = Jan21

env.workspace = r"X:\Support\Data\Shapes\"DATE_IS"\SA"
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking to automate it completely? Then you can use [datetime strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and [format](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp):

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.today().strftime('%b%y') #'Dec20'
arcpy.env.workspace = r"X:\Support\Data\Shapes\{}\SA".format(d)
```

Comment: Thank you this works a treat :)